# wrap long text in kable table column

Tags: r, knitr

I would like wrap long text in my kable table. Here is a simple example of a table with column text that is too long and needs to be wrapped for the table to fit on the page.

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
  library(knitr)
```


This is my test

```{r test, echo=FALSE}
test <- data.frame(v1=c("This is a long string. This is a long string. This is a long string. This is a long string. This is a long string.",
                        "This is a another long string. This is a another long string. This is a another long string. This is a another long string. This is a another long string."),
                   v2=c(1, 2))
kable(test)
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've created the `pander` package to produce markdown tables in a flexible way. By default, it will split cells with long string to 30 chars, but there are a bunch of [global options](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#general-options) and fn arguments to override that, enable hyphenation and other tweaks. Quick demo:

```
> pander::pander(test)

-----------------------------------
              v1                v2 
------------------------------ ----
This is a long string. This is  1  
a long string. This is a long      
string. This is a long string.     
    This is a long string.         

This is a another long string.  2  
This is a another long string.     
This is a another long string.     
This is a another long string.     
This is a another long string.     
-----------------------------------

> pander::pander(test, split.cell = 80, split.table = Inf)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                      v1                                         v2 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----
This is a long string. This is a long string. This is a long string. This is a   1  
                      long string. This is a long string.                           

This is a another long string. This is a another long string. This is a another  2  
  long string. This is a another long string. This is a another long string.        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: looks very slick, @daroczig. is there an argument for column names? sorry if I missed it.

Comment: Thank you @EricGreen. What argument do you miss for colnames? Probably you'd better set those at the `data.frame` level.

Comment: `kable` has `col.names` to redefine "v1" to "My text"

Comment: for my current use case, setting at the data.frame level worked fine. i'm not sure i would always want to do this, but nice in this case. great work on `pander`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @EricGreen. To be honest, I've never had any real need for such new argument in `pander` and I always tweak the actual `data.frame` to fit my needs before passing to `pander`, but if you can describe a good use-case, then please open an issue on GH.

Comment: Use case: tables without meaningful column names. For instance, I have a table where columns are defined by combinations of logical conditions (e.g. column 1 is the value when conditions 1, 2, and 3 are all true, column 2 has condition 3 false, etc.), and I want to represent this information compactly by making each condition a row with TRUE/FALSE and the values below rather than putting all that in each column heading. This is common in regression tables, for instance, but those usually also have meaningful column headers.

Answer (score 66):

An alternative solution other than the awesome `pander` package is to use `column_spec` in `kableExtra`. In this case, the following code will do the trick.

```
kable(test, "latex") %>%
  column_spec(1, width = "10em")
```

Comment: If your table is floating outside the page, `kable_styling(full_width = TRUE)` from the kableExtra package will also introduce wrapping of text if needed.

Comment: I think this should be clear  `kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)` when format in kable(format="latex"). So in this case wrapping text will not work.