# wrap long lines in kable() for use in Rnw/LaTeX

Tags: r, knitr

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425499/wrap-long-text-in-kable-table-column) a while back about how to wrap long table cell content in an RMarkdown document. A nice answer pointed to the `pander()` package.

I'm facing a similar issue again, only I'm working in an `Rnw` file, and my understanding is that `pander()` does not work with LaTeX. So I'm back to trying to figure out how to wrap long lines in `kable()`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

This is my test

<<test, echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
test <- data.frame(v1=c("This is a long string. This is a long string. This is a long string. This is a long string. This is a long string.",
                        "This is a another long string. This is a another long string. This is a another long string. This is a another long string. This is a another long string."),
                   v2=c(1, 2))
kable(test)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, @eric-green it looks like this questions really bother you a lot. lol I saw your [question about it earlier this year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29425499/wrap-long-text-in-kable-table-column) Why don't you submit a question on `knitr`'s github page?

Comment: It does not keep me up at night, but as noted in my question I did come across it before in a different form. I thought about submitting an issue, but I'm not sure that this is a problem that kable needs to solve. As the answer I accepted points out, xtable might fill this void.

Comment: I actually run into a similar case today and I found your posts. `xtable` is definitely not my favorite package and I would also love to see `kable` has this functionality in the future. :)

Comment: I've come around to xtable, but I also like the simplicity of kable. I guess it is hard to want lots of customization and simplicity at the same time

Comment: The above linked question has an answer using `kable()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are compiling the pdf with latex I recommend package `xtable` you can replicate almost everything you have in the tabular environment. The align option gives you what you want: l - left, c - center, r - right, or the size of the column. I added other options for you to play around. In the chunk options you have to add results = 'asis'.

```
library(xtable)
print(xtable(test, caption="A caption", align="lp{2cm}p{2cm}"), 
      comment=F, include.rownames=F, table.placement="ht", 
      size=getOption("xtable.size", "tiny"))
```

Comment: that's probably a good recommendation if there are no workarounds for `kable()`. i'll likely recommend this answer unless a `kable()` solution is posted (since this was my initial question). thanks!